# PHP Multidimensional Arrays - Creating and Reading Data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a little problem with multidimensional arrays. I think they are not like those in JAVA. For instance; I have created a array something like this;

```
$myArray = array();
```

Then I try to assign 4 different arrays to it as following.

```
$myArray[0] = $newArray0;
$myArray[1] = $newArray1;
$myArray[2] = $newArray2;
$myArray[3] = $newArray3;
```

But when I try to read a data from a cell with following line,

```
$myArray[0][2];
```

I could not get the data what I was hoping for. Can you guys tell me where am I mistaken?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the structure of your `$newArray0`, `$newArray1`, etc?

Comment: You can refer to multidimensional arrays like that, so there must be something wrong with the $newArrayX variables.

Comment: I get the same thing in my code when I try to do `$someArray[x]->someMethod();` - it just doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Actually those $newArrayXs are the arrays that are kept from database. Will there be any mistake in there? I use mysql_fetch_array function and hope to create an array consisting of some part of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got the right idea

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray1 = array("a","b","c");
$myArray2 = array("d","e","f");
$myArray3 = array("g","h","i");

$myArray[0] = $myArray1;
$myArray[1] = $myArray2;
$myArray[2] = $myArray3;

echo($myArray[0][2]);
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/ghOdBzoD)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do should work, try to make sure that $newArray0 is also a numeric array and not an associative array. You can find out how your array is being setup with the following code:

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($myArray);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

If you've done it the right way, the output must be something similar to:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [1] => Value,
    [2] => Value
  ),
  [1] => Array (
    [1] => Etc,
    [2] => Etc
  )
)
```

If that's what it says, then $myArray[0][2] should say 'Etc'.

Comment: What do you mean by associative array?

Comment: a numeric array is $array[0], $array[1], while an associative array contains DB fieldnames for example $array['user_id'] or $array['user_name']

Comment: Thus, if the 2nd was an associative array you would have had to use $myArray[0]['key_name'] for example. You can use mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) for a numeric resultset, MYSQL_ASSOC for an associative one and MYSQL_BOTH (which is the default) to get a resultset containing both: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php