# Make a multidimensional array of three array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make a array of arrays. 
Problem: 
My final array will be like this:

```
 Array(Array1, Array2, Array3);
     and arrays will be 
 Array1=Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 100 [2] => 100 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0
 Array2=Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 100 [2] => 100 [3] => 60 [4] => 0 [5] => 30 [6] => 0
 Array3=Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 100 [2] => 100 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 40
```

So how can make the multidimensional array and how can I access data from this array. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And the answer is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Multidimensional Arrays - Creating and Reading Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905137/php-multidimensional-arrays-creating-and-reading-data)

Comment: @rizier123 Thanks, I saw that but it is very complex to understand, Could you please provide a solution. It will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike a statically typed language, there is no need to declare these up front which can be confusing to newcomers. Really what you're describing is just a two-dimensional array. So really you have two options. Assuming these aren't associative like your example above, either putting arrays together:

```
$array = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Or if you are doing something with loops/iterators you can just define your two-d array on the fly:

```
$array[$itr][$inner_itr] = $array1[$inner_itr];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thnaks @Derek Dowling